# very specific emails stopped arriving to my me.com address

Tags: email, spam

I have had an account with a specific financial institution for several years now.  The email on file is a me.com address.

Any time I wish to do a financial transaction through their online service, they use 2FA via email to confirm that I genuinely requested the transaction.  This has always worked, never been an issue.

A couple of months ago, these emails stopped arriving.  They don't go to spam, they just don't arrive.  I have no such issue with any other communication from them such as marketing emails, etc.  The problem is strictly with these specific emails.  On their end, they think everything has gone just fine and that the emails were sent.  I have no issues with any other emails sent to this address from anyone at all.

I'm wondering if me.com has started flagging them for some reason as spam, and is blocking them before they ever reach me at all.  Is there some way I can validate/invalidate this idea?

I don't want to initiate a change of email address as I would have to go through their entire KYC/AML checks again (I'm in the USA) and it's a big pain, hoping I can just find the issue with the emails and solve that directly.

Comment: If sent ok (as they say), but not delivered (as you know), they should have received a message undelivered notification. If they have checked and haven't received one (and don't just delete them) you are left with going to the receiving mail service (Apple). Best of luck getting them to investigate!  Is the @me.com address associated with your iCloud account?

Comment: Indeed it is.  And yes I agree, good luck getting Apple to look into this.  Very frustrating.

Comment: My guess (and it doesn't help you!) is that they (the financial institution) are not using the right anti-spam protocols, DNS MX records and valid certificates when communicating from their 2FA mail server to Apple - in that case @me.com (Apple) may just ignore the connection. This guess is less likely if they are a large national financial institution.

Comment: Yeah they are not a large institution so you may be right.  Although everything was fine for a couple years or so, then suddenly this started, no idea why.

Comment: Find one of the previous emails that you did receive. Hopefully you have one.  Then call Apple Support.  They will need to see the headers on the email. Not the actual body of the message, just the headers. Click Edit -> Message -> All Headers. Send that bit to Apple. I bet money the financial institution isn't following best practices on those 2FA emails.

Comment: Yeah you could be right, but again they were coming without any issue for a couple years.  I guess maybe Apple could've tightened up something?  On that note, how do I contact someone at Apple that could actually help?  All I've ever been able to do is call with an issue on a specific product I own (computer, phone, etc.) and schedule a "genius" appointment.  Can't imagine I can call them and say "yeah I need to speak to your staff who handle the .me email filters please..."  Also I no longer have any of the old emails that did arrive so... moot point I guess.